# Give an example of this strange condition in metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

The condition is:

> There exists homeomorphic metric spaces $(X,d), (X,d')$ such that only one of them is complete.

But is this possible?, If it is can someone give the example please?

**Thanks a lot for the improvements, but the only thing that is changing is the metric not the space. And I think they are changing both in the answers :)**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the improvements, but the only thing that is changing is the metric not the space. And I think they are changing both in the answers :)

Comment: They're not, really - if $(X, d)$ is homeomorphic to $(X', d')$ via $f$, the function $d^*: X^2\rightarrow X: (x, y)\mapsto d'(f(x), f(y))$ is a metric on $X$, and we have $(X, d^*)$ is isometric to $(X', d)$. So we can just "port over" the metric on $X'$ to one on $X$.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/944416/8348).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot give a second to review :) that question.

Comment: Right, the thing is that I don't know topology stuff :)

Comment: Thanks Noah, but I haven't seen that :(